# Syncing Outlook calendar to Active Directory

Tags: outlook, directory, active-directory, synchronization

I am attempting (epic fail up to this point) to get data from Active Directory (Birthdays and Anniversary) to show up on a calendar that is posted on the internal site for my company. We do not use Azure Ad. We have a local AD. Any suggestion on how to pull the data that I need and have it sync to outlook calendar?

Answer (score 1):

•   Active Directory is a public key authentication system primarily, so it provides authentication claims and identity authorization for integrating applications based on it that retrieve information based on attributes requesting it.

•   So, to sync the information regarding birthday, there is no attribute with respect to it present in active directory. As a result, if you want the information regarding birthday to be in active directory, you will have to create a custom attribute regarding it in active directory and then fetch the data regarding that attribute using a script or a dependent application like exchange.

•   Below is the powershell script for adding the birthday in that custom attribute created: -

Import-CSV C:\ | For-EachObject { Set-ADUser $._userName -add @{"extensionAttirbute1" = $._UserBirthday}

•   Also, if you have exchange on premises in your environment, you can use the below command for getting calendar information regarding a user in exchange through which the dates will be synced in outlook calendar: -

Get-MailboxCalendarFolder -Identity kai:\Calendar -DomainController DC1

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/isingh/adding-custom-attributes-in-active-directory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailboxcalendarfolder?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Thank you. This gives me food for thought and direction when I did not have one. 

Again Thank you